# Changing radius of multiple points on D3 scatterplot based on condition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot

I'm using a function to build a series of d3 scatterplots.  Basically, each scatterplot shows a series of "cases", and then two events in time for each case.  On the Y-axis are the cases, on the X-axis are two events in time for each distinct case.  Picture here:

[image]

Each plot is based on one CSV, and the red/blue points are just plotting two different date columns for each "Case" record in the spreadsheet.

Each case is mapped on the scatterplot, each having two distinct events in time.  Currently, the radius of the circle will change when hovered over.  I want to be able to have both circles for each case change radius when either one is hovered over, so that there is a "linked" effect.  For example, if you hovered over either the blue or red dot for Case 1, both those circles would appear larger ( a way to visually link these two events for that case).

Here's the function that I'm using to build each scatterplot:

```
 function makeScatterplot(dataset, dataviz, field_1, field_2, field_3, numCases, maxAge, htmlText, xLabel, yLabel, legendItem1, legendItem2){
        
    //load csv//read the data
    d3.csv(dataset)
    .then(function(data) {

    //append svg to body of page
    var margin = {top: 60, right: 30, bottom: 50, left: 60},
    width = 580 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    var svg = d3.select(dataviz)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    //add x axis
    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0,maxAge])
        .range([0, width-100])
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .attr("class", "axisLine")  
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
        
    
    //add y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0,numCases])
        .range([ height, 0]);
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axisLine")  
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y)); 
        
    // text label for the x axis
    svg.append("text") 
        .attr("class", "axisLabel")     
        .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + ((width-100)/2 ) + " ," + 
                       (height + margin.top + -15) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Age");
                
        
    // Add the tooltip container to the vis container
    var tooltip = d3.select("#my_dataviz").append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0);
        
    //add dots for field 1 (red circles)
    svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("dot")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) {return x(d[field_1]);})
        .attr("cy", function (d) {return y(d.case);})
        .attr("r", 6)
        .attr("class", "events_1")
        .style("fill",  "ff4c4c")
        .style("opacity", '.7')
        .on("mouseover", function(data) {
            d3.select(this).attr("r", 10)
            d3.select('.tooltip')
            tooltip.transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", 1);
            tooltip.html(data[field_3] + htmlText)
            
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 15) + "px")
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 18) + "px");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(data) {
            d3.select(this).style("stroke", 'none')
            d3.select(this).attr("r", 6)
            tooltip.transition()
                .duration(500)
                .style("opacity", 0);
    })
    
    
    //add dots for field 2 (blue circles)
    svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("dot")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cy", function (d) {return y(d.case);})
        .attr("cx", function (d) {return x(d[field_2]);})
        .attr("r", 6) 
        .attr("class", "events_2")
        .style("fill",  "#6666ff")
        .style("opacity", '.8')
        .on("mouseover", function(data) {
            
                                            
            d3.select(this).attr("r", 10)
            this_case = data.case  // record the current case selected from blue circles on hover
            
            d3.selectAll(".events_1")  // change the radius of the red circle that matches the case selected from blue circles
                .attr("r", function(this_case){
                    d3.select(this)
                    this_case=data.case
                    console.log(this_case)
                    if (this_case) {
                        return 10
                    }
                    else {
                        return  6
                    }
                })  


                return this_case
                            
                
            //.data(data.filter(function(d){return d.case == d.case;}))
            d3.select('.tooltip')
            tooltip.transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", 1);
            tooltip.html(data[field_3] + htmlText)
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 15) + "px")
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 18) + "px");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(data) {
            d3.select(this).style("stroke", 'none')
            d3.select(this).attr("r", 6)
            tooltip.transition()
                .duration(500)
                .style("opacity", 0);
    })
                
    })
            
}

//Build scatterplots by calling function
makeScatterplot(dataset_suicide, dataviz_1, demo_dod, avi_suicide_date, suicide_to_DOD, 22, 70, suicide_html, xLabel, yLabel, suicide_title, dod_legend, suicide_legend, )
makeScatterplot(dataset_DOC, dataviz_1, demo_dod, doc_inc_release_dte, release_to_DOD, 20, 70, DOC_html,  xLabel, yLabel, DOC_title, dod_legend, doc_legend)
makeScatterplot(dataset_last_od, dataviz_2, demo_dod, avi_od_date, od_to_death, 41, 75, last_od_html,  xLabel, yLabel, last_od_title, dod_legend, last_od_legend)
```

Currently, this code is applying the radius to ALL cases when a blue circle is hovered:

[image]

Is there an easy way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?  Basically, just trying to link these circles on hover, for each separate scatterplot (circle radius would only increase for circles selected within the scatterplot, from the same case, not for all scatterplots).

I'm guessing I might need to have the circle classes be a variable parameter so they can be selected accordingly.

Comment: This should be easy to fix if you are able to make a codepen/blockbuilder with some sample data. Could you possibly share that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do with your `if` statement, but when you define the variable `this_case` as the object being passed to your function for `r`, to d3 this is whatever data object is bound to each individual selected object - overriding the scope I think you're trying to create for `this_case` a few lines above.

Whilst keeping your first definition for `this_case`, try renaming your variable passed into the function's scope, something like this, where I've just changed it to `d`:

```
                .attr("r", function(d){
                    if (d.case == this_case) {
                        return 10
                    }
                    else {
                        return  6
                    }
                })
```

*Alternative approach:* If it were me, I would probably append just one `g` tag for each case, with an id something including the case number. I would then append both circles to this tag, so that on mouseover I could select the appropriate `g` tag first with the id I created, and then on that do a `selectAll('circle')` to change both of the circles. Just feels a bit more structured, but of course, that's just my opinion!